# Сохранение изображения в тот же файл, из которого оно было создано

Tags: c#, winforms

Пишу команды для работы с файловым меню. Возникла проблема: если открываю изображение, а потом пытаюсь в него же сохранить, то вылетает ошибка `ExternalException`. Про нее написано на msdn, что возникает, если:

1) Изображение было сохранено в неправильном формате.

2) Изображение сохранено в тот же файл, из которого оно было создано.

Как тогда перезаписывать в файл в таком случае? Пока пришла только такая идея: создавать дополнительный файл с другим именем, туда сохранять изображение. Далее - удалять первое изображение, а потом переименовывать новый файл в старое имя. Но это геморрой.

Кто-нибудь знает, как это можно нормально реализовать? Скидываю ниже код, когда вылетает ошибка:

```
public Form1()
{
    //InitializeComponent();
    Size = new Size(1000, 1000);
    var bitmap = new Bitmap(1, 1);
    var fullExistFileName = "";
    var pictureBox = new PictureBox() { Parent = this, BackColor = SystemColors.ControlLightLight, Size = new Size(800, 800), Location = new Point(50, 50) };
    var buttonToOpen = new Button { Parent = this, BackColor = SystemColors.Control, Size = new Size(70, 20), Location = new Point(60, 20), Text = "Открыть" };
    var buttonToSave = new Button { Parent = this, BackColor = SystemColors.Control, Enabled = false, Size = new Size(70, 20), Location = new Point(140, 20), Text = "Сохранить" };

    buttonToOpen.Click += (o, e) =>
    {
        var openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        openFileDialog.Filter = "Все файлы изображений(*.BMP;*.PNG;*.JPEG;*.GIF)|*.BMP;*.PNG;*.JPG;*.GIF|PNG|*.png|JPEG|*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.jpe;*.jfif|GIF|*.gif";

        if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            bitmap = new Bitmap(openFileDialog.FileName);
            fullExistFileName = openFileDialog.FileName;
        }

        buttonToSave.Enabled = true;
        pictureBox.Invalidate();
    };

    buttonToSave.Click += (o, e) =>
    {
        var saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
        saveFileDialog.Filter = "PNG|*.png|JPEG|*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.jpe;*.jfif|BMP|*.bmp|GIF|*.gif";
        saveFileDialog.FileName = fullExistFileName;

        if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            var newBitmap = new Bitmap(pictureBox.Width, pictureBox.Height);
            pictureBox.DrawToBitmap(newBitmap, pictureBox.ClientRectangle);
            newBitmap.Save(saveFileDialog.FileName);
        }
    };

    pictureBox.Paint += (o, e) =>
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(bitmap, 0, 0);
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
  var newBitmap = new Bitmap(pictureBox.Width, pictureBox.Height);
  pictureBox.DrawToBitmap(newBitmap, pictureBox.ClientRectangle);

  bitmap.Dispose();
  newBitmap.Save(saveFileDialog.FileName);
  bitmap = newBitmap;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, не думал, что обычное освобождение ресурсов решит этот вопрос

Comment: Битмап, загруженый из файла, не отпускает файл до вызова Dispose.